# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have the following code written in my `.js` file:

```
var tiles = document.querySelectorAll(".tile");
var tileNumbers = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];

for(var i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++){
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * tileNumbers.lenth);
    tiles.classList.add(tileNumbers[num]);
    tileNumbers.pop(num);
}
```

The `.tile` are 4 `<div>`'s in the .html file, and I am trying to add a class each of the four tiles separately. The classes are held in `tileNumbers`. When I run the code in Chrome I get the error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined."

I am pretty sure everything is spelled correctly. Please help!

Comment: Change `tiles` => `tiles[i]` in `for()`.

Comment: Also, a typo: `tileNumbers.lenth` should be `tileNumbers.length`

Comment: Also, `tileNumbers.pop(num);` doesn't do what you likely think, since the `.pop()` doesn't take an argument. You're probably looking for `.splice(num, 1)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to call `add` on the tile, but try to access the `add` function of the `tiles` array itself. This does not exist.

What you need to do is to access the `add` function of each individual tile. To do so, first get it:

```
var tile = tiles[i];
```

Then, change your call to

```
tile.classList.add(…);
```

(You could also omit the temporary variable `tile`, and use `tiles[i].classList.add` directly. But IMHO using a dedicated variable makes the code more clear to read.)

Another option, which may be even better, is to use `forEach`. Since you use the `i` only for accessing the current element and nothing else, you basically want to perform an action on each element. You can do it like this as well (and, for bonus points, this even protects you against off-by-one errors):

```
tiles.forEach(function (tile) {
  // ...
});
```

Then, within the function body, you automatically have a variable `tile` that you can access in the way you want to.

That's it :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, another question: I added "[i]" right after tiles and before ".classList", and I get an "undefined" class on all of the tile's class lists.

Comment: PS: If this answered your question, it would be great if you could mark this answer as accepted :-)

Comment: Look up, I posted another question, but yes I will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
tiles[i].classList.add(tileNumbers[num]);
```

Not

```
tiles.classList.add(tileNumbers[num]);
```